# How to hide folder in external directory Android

Tags: android, directory, hide, external

I download pdf files into a folder in an external directory on a project. But on windows computers, they can access it when they connect the phone to the computer. How can I store these files or folders? I try to put a (.) Per name of folder in fakay again in windows. I can not use getFilesDir, old software developers did the project according to the external directory

Do you have any information on this issue?

Comment: Use `getFilesDir()`. Try it. You can!

Comment: `the build is in accordance with the external directory.` ???? What do you mean?

Comment: Old software developers did the project according to the external directory so I can not use getFilesDir()

Comment: If you are trying to prevent the user from accessing the content, there is no advantage to using external storage and only disadvantages. "Old software developers did the project according to the external directory so I can not use getFilesDir() " -- when somebody asks for clarification, simply repeating yourself does not help. So, I agree with the recommendation to use `getFilesDir()`.